# Get contents of php file after it's ran/executed

Tags: php, file

How can I put the result of an include into a PHP variable?

I tried `file_get_contents` but it gave me the actual PHP code, whereas I want whats echoed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either capture anything that's printed in the include file through output buffering

```
ob_start();
include 'yourFile.php';
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

or alternatively, set a return value in the script, e.g.

```
// included script
return 'foo';
// somewhere else
$foo = include 'yourFile.php';
```

See Example 5 of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Also interesting to note that [ob_start()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) accepts a callback argument. (It took me a while to notice.)

Answer (score 3):

or simply return a value from an included file as explained [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

```
return.php:
<?php

$var = 'PHP';

return $var;

?>


$foo = include 'return.php';

echo $foo; // prints 'PHP'
```